# Position div above element w/ jQuery + CSS

Tags: css

I have an icon in the middle of a text sentence. When the icon is clicked I need to position a div box above the icon, preferably aligning the top-left corner of the box with the icon.

I tried using position: relative for the box but it still appears below the text line. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say the height of the div is 100px. Than just add `top: -100px`

Comment: Hmm, do I need to place the icon inside some element, like a <DIV>? My box now appears way down and to the right, with top: 10px and left:10px.

Comment: Oops, changed position to absolute and it fixed it.

Comment: @santa Yeah forgot to mention position:absolute .. So its all good now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, find a tooltip plugin that can be actived with the onclick event

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your div is displayed on top of the icon, make it's written after the icon in the HTML.

Otherwise you can specify a greater z-index property for the div.

To move it on top of the icon you have to change its coordinates values or playing with margins. Eventually you may also need to set its position to absolute with `position:absolute` in the css;